# How to easy convert LPBYTE to char[256] (used to read text from windows registry)

Tags: c++, char, lpbyte

**How I can convert LPBYTE to char [256]?**

When I read from Windows registry value:

blah REG_SZ "blah some text"

```
char value[256];
DWORD keytype = REG_SZ;
DWORD dwCount = sizeof(value);
RegQueryValueEx((HKEY)key, "blah", 0, &keytype, (LPBYTE)&value, &count);
 cout << "Read text from registry: " << value << endl;
```

after cout this it shows (screenshot):

http://i33.tinypic.com/dnja4i.jpg

(normal text + some signs)

I must compare value from registry:

```
 if("blah some text" == value)
  cout << "Kk, good read from registry\n";
```

How I can convert this LPBYTE value to char[256] ?

Comment: If this is in C++, why don't you just use `std::string`?

Answer (score 3):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724911(VS.85).aspx):

> If the data has the REG_SZ,
>   REG_MULTI_SZ or REG_EXPAND_SZ type,
>   the string may not have been stored
>   with the proper terminating null
>   characters. Therefore, even if the
>   function returns ERROR_SUCCESS, the
>   application should ensure that the
>   string is properly terminated before
>   using it; otherwise, it may overwrite
>   a buffer. (Note that REG_MULTI_SZ
>   strings should have two terminating
>   null characters.) One way an
>   application can ensure that the string
>   is properly terminated is to use
>   RegGetValue, which adds terminating
>   null characters if needed.

After querying the value, you should set value[dwCount-1] to '\0' to ensure it is null terminated.

Or just use [RegGetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724868(VS.85).aspx) which removes a lot of the oddness in the registry API - guarantees null terminated strings, allows you to specify the expected data type and fail if it is otherwise, automatically expands REG_EXPAND_SZ's, etc.

Comment: When I add (LPBYTE)value it shows me text like in image: http://i33.tinypic.com/dnja4i.jpg

Comment: @Lisa ignore my initial answer - I knew it was wrong the moment I submitted it.

Comment: Ty Michael I will try that and write about it :)

Answer (score 2):

After the `RegQueryValueEx` call, you need to set the `NUL`-byte at the end of your string, using the value written by the function in `dwCount` :

```
value[dwCount] = 0;
```

Note that you can't compare two strings using `==` as they are pointers, use the `strcmp` function to compare them :

```
if (strcmp(value, "blah") == 0)
    puts("Strings are equal");
```

(`strcmp` can be found in the `string.h` header)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement RegGetVAlue function from Michaels answer, but I got Advapi32.dll error after compiling.
When I set value[dwCount] and compare string with code from delroth answer, everything works fine :)
Thank you Michael, delroth :)

Comment: Please don't respond with another answer -- edit your original question instead.  When you get more rep, you can then use comments as well.